# How to count values in a multi layered array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, collections

Is there a simple way to count the values in a multi layered array like this?

```
from collections import Counter

a = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

print(Counter(a))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(Counter(a))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 653, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the list first using a generator expression, what you're doing now is counting the lists, not the elements inside them:

```
>>> print(Counter(i for b in a for i in b))
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

With `map` and `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> print(reduce(Counter.__add__, map(Counter, a)))
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

If you need counts for each sublist independently, then use this list comprehension instead:

```
>>> print([Counter(b) for b in a])
[Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}), Counter({4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})]
```

Comment: This works but is there no way for doing this without `for loop`/`list comprehension` ?

Comment: The first one, sorry

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov You can use `map` to create a counter for each sublist, and then `reduce` to add all the counts together.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply count like this

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(sum(len(a) for a in a))
```

> gives you count as 6